# Accessing variable from helpers file in views - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have made a helpers file in my /app folder which contains the following:

```
$constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
foreach ($constants as $constant) {
    $C[$constant->type] = $constant->value;
}
echo $C['business_name'];
```

This works, but if I try

```
echo $C['business_name'];
```

In one of my views I get an error of $C undefined. I have added the helpers file to my start/global file and I know it works...

What steps should I take to use this variable in my views?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data directly into the view via the second parameter of `View::make` or alternatively `View::make('someBlade')->with(data);`

So in your case it might be something like:
`View::make('someBlade', $C);`

If you really, really want globals, you can do this for views:
`View::share('c', $C);`

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a function in helper and call that function in view.
it will automatically display value of this variable but you need change "echo" replacing with "return" in function last line.

```
function xyz()
{

$constants = DB::table('constants')->get();
foreach ($constants as $constant) {
    $C[$constant->type] = $constant->value;
}

return $C['business_name'];

}

Call this function in your view like this. {{xyz()}}
```

if you are returning array {? $abc=xyz(); ?} make blade filter not echoing value pass this function to array variable and show like this {{$abc['business_name']}}